# Eclipse on Mac: Adding SWT reference to Swing app: App doesn't launch

Tags: java, macos, swing, jar, swt

On Mac, when I add a SWT reference to a Swing app, the app/.jar doesn't launch anymore.

However doing the same thing on Windows works fine and I can load a Swing JFrame with SWT components.

On Mac, standalone SWT works fine, but I can't add SWT components to Swing JFrame. I have tried both SWT Mac builds.

Edit:

Seems to be a bug in Eclipse, since it works to launch the .jar if it's exported but not if I'm debugging.

Comment: Do you get any errors/exceptions when running the jar from the console?

Comment: No, no exception nothing happens. The build just refuses to start.

Comment: Hmm, after exporting the app as a runnable .jar I can run it. Just can't run it in Eclipse. Weird...

Comment: What are your VM arguments?  Are you passing `-XstartOnFirstThread`?

Comment: Probably yes, haven't modified anything...